# Resoponsive width size for ( 5.5 inch or less mobile width)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, responsive

In your opinion, what should be the size of the 5.5 inch or fewer mobile width for responsive? I use the w3-schools standard, but when I test it, in 5.5-inch is not a responsive site and it's broken.I considered 480px minimum size. should I consider less? for example, 320 pixels.

Comment: I always treat 320px as standard mobile resolution. I don't care about any lesser than that, but that is the minimum where your page should not break.

Comment: Check this website - https://lascarides.github.io/screenres.html

Comment: @BalázsVarga thanks bro

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke thanks bro

Comment: Just FYI: The pixel dimensions of a screen have rather little to do with the display size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following media query breakpoint widths as a general rule:

320px - Phones (I usually style to this first, then use the other values as media queries)
600px - Tablets in Portrait
900px - Tablets in Landscape/Small laptops
1200px - Most computers
1800px - Large displays

Answer (score 0):

Better solution would be to use Mobile first approach, that way we can control smaller screens far better and work through our way for larger monitors